# How can we dynamically change the width and height of a png image created using GD library in PHP?

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2

I created a chessboard using GD library and saved as png file. I followed this solution (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php#59222). But I need to change width and height of image and width of field (square column in chessboard) dynamically. Any help would be appreciated.

### HTML

```
    <form action="" method="get">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="height">Height</label>
          <input type="number" name="height" id="height" class="form-control" placeholder="Height">
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="width">Width</label>
          <input type="number" name="width" id="width" class="form-control" placeholder="Width">
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="fieldWidth">Field Width</label>
           <input type="number" name="fieldWidth" id="fieldWidth" class="form-control" placeholder="Field Width">
       </div>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="generateImage">Generate Image</button>

   </form>
```

### php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['generateImage'] )) {
          //header('Content-type: image/png');

    $imageCreate = @imagecreate(400, 400)
                    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
    $grey        = imagecolorallocate($imageCreate, 229, 229, 229);
    $black       = imagecolorallocate($imageCreate,0,0,0);
    $white       = imagecolorallocate($imageCreate,255,255,255);
    $fieldWidth  = (!empty($_REQUEST['fieldWidth'])) ? $_REQUEST['fieldWidth'] : 50;

    imagefilltoborder($imageCreate, 0, 0, $grey, $grey);

    imagefill($imageCreate,50,20, $white);

    for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $cord = $i * $fieldWidth;
        imageline($imageCreate,0, $cord,400, $cord, $black);
        imageline($imageCreate, $cord,0, $cord,400, $black);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++)  {
        for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++)  {
             $x = ($i * $fieldWidth) + 2;
             $y = ($j * $fieldWidth) + 2;
             if ( (($i % 2) + ($j % 2) ) % 2 == 0 ) {
                imagefill($imageCreate, $x, $y, $black);
             }
        }
    }

    imagepng($imageCreate, 'img/chessboard.png');
    imagedestroy($imageCreate);

}
```

Comment: Maybe you would be better off building it with HTML and CSS? Responsive design should then be easier. https://coderbyte.com/tutorial/create-a-simple-chessboard-using-html-css-and-jquery How often do you need resizing, just once or multiple times?

Comment: @user3783243 If I built with HTML and CSS is it possible to save as .png file using GD library?. Multiple times resizing.

Comment: No, but do you need an image? I was figuring you were using the image later as an underlay for a chess presentation. If that were the case you could just overlay the pieces on the HTML.